# Calculating difference between two dates in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I'm working with a dataframe and need to calculate the number of days (as integer) between two dates formatted as timestamp

I've opted for this solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, when, col, datediff
df1 = df1.withColumn("LD", datediff("MD", "TD"))
```

But after calculating sum from a list I get an error: "Column in not iterable" which makes me impossible to calculate sum of the rows based on column names

```
col_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
df2 = df1.withColumn("My_Sum", sum([F.col(c) for c in col_list]))
```

How can I deal with it in order to calculate the difference between dates and then calculate the sum of the rows given the names of certain columns?

Comment: `sum([F.col(c) for c in col_list])` does not calculate sum of the rows. let's say your column name is `a`, then a sum window of `a` will give you the sum of the rows in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The `datediff` has nothing to do with the `sum` of a column. The pyspark sql `sum` function takes in **1 column** and it calculates the sum of the rows in that column.

Here are a couple of ways to get the sum of a column from a list of columns using list comprehension.

*Single row output with the sum of the column*

```py
data_sdf. \
    select(*[func.sum(c).alias(c+'_sum') for c in col_list]). \
    show()

# +-----+-----+-----+
# |a_sum|b_sum|c_sum|
# +-----+-----+-----+
# | 1337| 3778| 6270|
# +-----+-----+-----+
```

*the sum of all rows of the column in each row*

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    select('*',
           *[func.sum(c).over(wd.partitionBy()).alias(c+'_sum') for c in col_list]
           ). \
    show(5)

# +---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
# |  a|  b|  c|a_sum|b_sum|c_sum|
# +---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
# | 45| 58|125| 1337| 3778| 6270|
# |  9| 99|143| 1337| 3778| 6270|
# | 33| 91|146| 1337| 3778| 6270|
# | 21| 85|118| 1337| 3778| 6270|
# | 30| 55|101| 1337| 3778| 6270|
# +---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
# only showing top 5 rows
```